# I can't do the map function on a nested object in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to React and was trying some use cases to improve my knowledge of React.
I can't seem to make the map function work on a nested object.

What I wanted to do was to pass the current object to a child component and use it there to be displayed. So I want to make 2 divs where one is for credit and one is for debit. My thought process was that I thought that I can make one initial object here, pass the specific object to the component and display it.

Below are my codes:

```
const [InputFields, setInputFields] = useState([
{
   credit: {
       minimumBalance: '',
       maximumBalance: '',
       interestRate: '',
   }
   debit: {
       minimumBalance: '',
       maximumBalance: '',
       interestRate: '',
   }
}]);

console.log(InputFields.credit) //result will get undefined


return(
   <Fragment>
     <div>
       {InputFields.credit.map((inputField, index) => {
         return(
           <EditInterestRate key={index} inputFields={inputField.debit} />
         );
       })}
     </div>
   </Fragment>
);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an array of objects so `console.log(InputFields.credit)` will not work as you're trying to directly reference a property that's not defined on the entire array but for every individual element of the array.
`console.log(InputFields[0].credit)`
Is the correct way. Therefore you need to loop through your input InputField and then use map to get individual field and then reference the credit and debit properties.

```
InputField.map((inputField,index)=>{
    return(
           <EditInterestRate key={index} inputFields={inputField.debit} />
     );
})
```

Something on the above lines. In your code you're trying to access the `debit` property inside your `credit` property when they both exist as individual properties.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, `console.log(InputFields.credit)` is `undefined` because, `InputFields` is initialized as an array. According to your code if you want to get the data, then the code should be:

```
console.log(InputFields[0].credit)
```

**Now, in case of** `map` **method:**

you can only apply javascript `map` function on an array not on an object. In your code snippet you are trying to map over `InputFields.credit` which is an object, not an array. That's why you are getting the error.

Answer (score 0):

First thing is you forgot to add comma after closing curly bracket of credit.
`const [InputFields, setInputFields] = useState([ { credit: { minimumBalance: '', maximumBalance: '', interestRate: '', } , debit: { minimumBalance: '', maximumBalance: '', interestRate: '', } }]);`

Second thing,you have to do console.log(InputFields[0].credit.minimumBalance) in order to log something in the console.